# copy List<Type> to another another instance variable

Tags: java

I am passing in to a callback method (List a) and I want to know how to copy over the value.

```
List<addresses> mInstanceList;
public void setMyList(List<Address> addresses)
{
  mInstanceList = addresses;     // is this going to work?
}
```

Comment: Define "work". Do you want to *copy* list items, or just the list reference? (I'm assuming the different types are a typo.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean new copy? If so, you may do something like `mInstanceList=new Arraylist(addresses);`

Comment: You could also try `mInstanceList.subList(0, mInstanceList.size() - 1)` but I suspect creating a new instance will be faster & you'll be assured of the actual implementation of the list, if that's important to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

There you are copying the reference to the list that *addresses* points to *mInstanceList*. If someone else changes the elements of that list, it will be reflected in *mInstanceList*. 
If you don't want that, you can create a new list (maybe an ArrayList) and copy the contents of the *addresses* list, in the same order.

```
mInstanceList = new ArrayList<Address>();
for (Address a: addresses) {
    mInstanceList.add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you want to copy a list and assign it to a List Reference Variable having its very own copy, then use `Copy Constructor`.

**Eg:**

```
ArrayList<Address> list1 = new ArrayList<Address>();

ArrayList<Address> list2 = new ArrayList<Address>(list2);
```

**Change made into the ArrayList object referred by list1 will not reflected into ArrayList object referred by list2, as they both are pointing to 2 different ArrayList object on the heap.**

**2.** If you just want to make to List Reference Variable pointing on the same object on the heap, then do this..

```
ArrayList<Address> list1 = new ArrayList<Address>();

ArrayList<Address> list2 = list1 ;
```

**As now both the references list1 and list2 are pointing on the same ArrayList object on the heap, changes made by one will be reflected in another.**